# How to Add tap gesture to part of NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am using a `UILabel` and setting its attributed text.

I want to add tap gesture to part of string rather than part of label. Because my `UILabel` is a multiline one.

I can't add gesture to part of label.

How can I add gesture to part of string.
For example:

```
lblObject.text = @"Hi Abdul, did you see my BACKBONE book."
```

I want to add gesture to BACKBONE text only.

[image]

I want to add tap gesture to the underlined text .

Both the red box are a single text in two different lines.

Comment: You need to use the hyperlink functionality of attributed string. That's not easy out of the box but https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel has been around a while and can do most of the heavy lifting leaving you to implement a delegate.

Comment: you can add UILabel as subView in UILabel (main Label). Now set required text as you want & Add gesture on subView UILabel...

Comment: @BrittoThomas. Because my UILabel is a multi line one. And the text that i want to add gesture to is on two line. I am attaching screenshot. Please review.

Comment: Use UITextView then set its Detections and perform your desired actions